# SharePoint Online rename list column title

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, column

I am trying to figure out how to rename a list column on SharePoint Online, for example I would like to rename the column "Category2" to "Category".

I have seen JS examples of doing this on SP2013 however doesn't seem to work.

My column ID is: **diidSort18Category20**

I've previously tried this code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
 _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("ChangeColumnName"); // Call ChangeColumnName function on PageLoad
        function ChangeColumnName() 
          {
            RenameColumn('diidSort18Category20', 'Category'); //Provide Column ID and New Column name
        }
        function RenameColumn(colID, NewHeader) {
            try {
                document.getElementById(colID).innerHTML = NewHeader; //Change Header Name
                document.getElementById(colID).title = "Sort by " + NewHeader; // Change Tooltip value
            }
            catch (err) {
                alert('Invalid Column ID:' + colID);
            }
        }
 </script>
```

Comment: Are trying to rename it by script? why dont you rename manually.

Comment: I cant rename manually as "Category" is a system-reserved column and can only be used as a plain-text field. We need to use the Category2 column as a choice field.

Comment: What kind of list template or Content Types are being used? "Category" is not a system reserved column. (Create a new list from the "Document" or "Custom" templates and add a new column named "Category".

Comment: Do you want change the Display name of the field or internal name.

Comment: I've managed to get round this by renaming the reserved fields on the site columns and then creating new fields under a new column group.